# How to properly handle error on mongoose CRUD

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud

I am building a very simple RESTFUL app to see how Node and Mongo work together.

A made a function to find a "Persona" document on a mongodb by Id, so here is the code:

```
function getPersonabyId(req,res)
{
    //en params del objeto request esta lo que llega por get
    let idPersona=req.params.id;

    //mongoose trae un método para pillar por id
    Persona.findById(idPersona).exec((err,objPersona)=>
    {

        if(err)
        {
           res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        else{


            res.status(200).send(objPersona);
        }

    })


}
```

And I use this route, where function is executed:

```
miniApp.get("/getPersonaById/:id",controladorPersona.getPersonabyId);
```

So, when I pass as parameter a valid ID, everything is ok, I get the proper Persona object in the response.

But when I use a not valid ID (no document with that ID exists on the mongodb), the error specified on the exec callback is thrown... but, isn´t supossed that this error should be thrown only in case there are server problems? a non existent ID should not be a 500 error, isn´t it?

I looked for info and I found this:

https://coursework.vschool.io/mongoose-crud/

```
Person.find((err, people) => {  
    // Note that this error doesn't mean nothing was found,
    // it means the database had an error while searching, hence the 500 status
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err)
    // send the list of all people
    return res.status(200).send(people);
});
```

And reading the commented lines on the code above, confuses me even more... the error, as said in those comments, should be an error database or something similar, not a "not found" error... but the error is  actually thrown when an object with that ID is not found!

This is the error I get with a non valid ID:

```
{
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"5b105ba453401c41d0e3da2\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Persona\"",
    "name": "CastError",
    "stringValue": "\"5b105ba453401c41d0e3da2\"",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": "5b105ba453401c41d0e3da2",
    "path": "_id"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using mongoose, you can validate that the incoming value is an objectId or not by using mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id). This will return a boolean and possibly save you some effort or writing the regex for object Id validation.

Comment: Thanks! very useful!

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your `_id` as `ObjectId` in schema. Not every string is a valid `ObjectId`. the id tha you are passing to `findById` is not valid. Object id should be 24 characters long string. Add this check before querying,

```
if (id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
  // Yes, it's a valid ObjectId, proceed with `findById` call.
} else{
  //throw an error
}
```

or if you want to keep using any string as `_id`, define `_id` as `String` instead of `ObjectId` in your schema.